# Пример использования команды pivot_root в Debian

Tags: linux

Задача состоит в том, чтобы систему полностью перекинуть на новую директорию, где уже лежат все необходимые для загрузки системы файлы. Хотелось бы использовать pivot_root. И вообще, можно ли полностью переключить систему с одного корня на другой?
Хотелось бы увидеть подробную инструкцию, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

[pivot_root(8)](https://ru.manpages.org/pivot_root/2) используется на этапах ранней загрузки для переключения из initrd   на реальный корень.

[pivot_root(2)](https://manpages.org/pivot_root/8) изменяет корневую систему **только вызывающего процесса**. На этапе initrd процесс только один - поэтому это выглядит как смена корня всей системы. Также создает точку монтирования старого корня. Поэтому это дает возможность отмонтировать рамдиск.

Пример использования

```
mount /dev/sda1 /new-root
cd /new-root
pivot_root . old-root
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1

umount /old-root
```

Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Но замена рабочего корня на PC делается с перезагрузкой так:

```
mount -B /dev/ /new-root/dev
mount -B /sys/ /new-root/sys
mount -B /proc/ /new-root/proc
chroot /new-root/

grub-install
update-grub
exit

reboot
```

Comment: при выполнении команды pivot_root . oldroot возникает ошибка: 
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `oldroot/': Недопустимый аргумент
директорию oldroot конечно же создал

Comment: Всетаки чего именно хотите добиться?

Comment: у меня в /mnt/newroot лежит новая система, мне надо сделать /mnt/newroot новым корнем системы, чтобы машина запускалась с обновленным корнем

Comment: Так pivot тут не причём. Смотри вторую часть ответа

Comment: root@root:/# grub-install /dev/sda1 
Выполняется установка для платформы i386-pc.
grub-install: предупреждение: Файловая система «ext2» не поддерживает встраивание.
grub-install: предупреждение: Встраивание невозможно. При имеющихся параметрах GRUB можно установить только с помощью списка блоков (blocklists). Однако, список блоков является НЕНАДЁЖНЫМ механизмом и его лучше не использовать..
grub-install: ошибка: не будет продолжена с использованием blocklists.

Comment: команда update-grub срабатывает и находит образ, но после выхода из chroot'a и ребута, не меняется ничего. насколько я понимаю именно потому, что chroot это история изоляции, и она никак не влияет на основную систему

Comment: Почему в sda1? Без единички в сам диск который выбран загрузочный в биос

Comment: Нет, это потому что загрузчик смотрит в старый /boot/. `grub-install /dev/sda` установит загрузчик с новой директорией  boot в загрузочный сектор

Comment: Это правда сработает если новый корень на разделе. И не забудь про fstab в новом корне

Comment: а если раздел всего один? можно ли как-то поменять корень системы на новую директорию?

Comment: можно, для этого в  initramfs нужно перед  run-init выполнить скрипт. в переменную загрузки ядра добавляешь  `BOOT=myfolder` . в скрипте  `/scripts/myfolder`  можешь попробовать или перезаписать переменную ${rootmnt} или через mount -o bind  подвинуть рут

Comment: а можно, пожалуйста, подробнее по комментарию выше?